Relation between two theories of degree of maps
For a holomorphic map between 2 Riemann surfaces, we can define its degree to be the sum of ramification index of all preimages of a point, or simply the cardinality of the preimage of a regular(not critical) point.
In algebraic topology, there is a way of defining degree of a map from the $n$-sphere to itself via its induced action on the $n$-th homology of the space.
These two definitions both work for the 2-dimensioanl sphere, i.e. the Riemann sphere. My question is: Do they coincide in this setting?

Yes. You might want to read through this and then attempt a proof yourself. Also note that there's no need to restrict to the sphere: You can just as well talk about the degree of a map between arbitrary closed oriented manifolds of the same dimension by considering the action of $f$ on top-degree homology (which via the orientation identifies with $\mathbb{Z}$).

what definition of homology are you using?

@AndresMejia In my mind I'm thinking of singular homology, but I guess all homology theories are the same for Euclidean spheres?
